# I've created a simple calculator in OOP way in python. I get an error message, that my variables are not defined

Tags: python, oop

So that's my calc, I was trying to do it to understand class decorators better

```
class Calc():

   @staticmethod
   def add(x, y):
       return x + y

  .
  .
  .

   @staticmethod
   def div(x, y):
       return x / y

   @staticmethod
   def get_numbers():
       num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
       num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
       return num1, num2

   @staticmethod
   def get_operator():
       operator = input('Please enter an operator (+, -, *, /): ')
    return operator

   @classmethod
   def calculate(cls):
       cls.get_numbers()
       cls.get_operator()
       if operator == '+':
           print(add(num1, num2))
       elif operator == '-':
           print(sub(num1, num2))
       elif operator == '*':
           print(mul(num1, num2))
       elif operator == '/':
           print(div(num1, num2))


Calc.calculate()
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc_feltoltesre.py", line 44, in <module>
     Calc.calculate()
  File "calc_feltoltesre.py", line 32, in calculate
     get_numbers()
 NameError: name 'get_numbers' is not defined
```

I have no idea, why the operator and num1 and num2 are not visible in the scope.

Comment: Your traceback and the code you posted don't line up. Note that the code you posted uses `cls.get_numbers()`, but the traceback doesn't have the `cls.` prefix. Are you sure you *saved* your work?

Comment: Also, why use a class *at all* when all you have is class methods and static methods? You may as well make this all into functions in a module.

Comment: Just for basic practice. It could help me the undestand the basisc of decorators.

Comment: Please post the code that produces your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong with your `calculate` method.

First off, to get access to what your functions `get_numbers()` and `get_operator()` return, you need to store the values inside a variable.
Second, you also need to add `cls.` to your `add`, `sub`, `mul` and `div` calls (inside the print statement) or else it will give you a `NameError` since those methods aren't defined.

Try this out:

```
@classmethod
def calculate(cls):
    num1, num2 = cls.get_numbers()
    operator = cls.get_operator()
    if operator == '+':
        print (cls.add(num1, num2))
    elif operator == '-':
        print (cls.sub(num1, num2))
    elif operator == '*':
        print (cls.mul(num1, num2))
    elif operator == '/':
        print (cls.div(num1, num2))
```